# Onclick listner not triggering in fragment page adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to display all contacts from phone to `recyclerView` when a user presses any item it should do some work. I have a list of contacts in a fragment which is inside a fragment page adapter when ever I click in the `recyclerView` item `onClicklistener` is not executing

I have used same code in a previous app but `onclicklisteners` are triggering

```
   public class ListOfContacts extends Fragment implements OnContactListener {
    private static final String TAG = "ListOfContacts";
    ArrayList<ContactModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView mRecyclerview;
    ListOfContactsRAdapter listOfContactsRAdapter;
    Cursor cursor;

    public static ListOfContacts getInstance(ArrayList<ContactModel> arrayList) {
        ListOfContacts listOfContacts = new ListOfContacts();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("listofcontacts", arrayList);
        listOfContacts.setArguments(bundle);
        return listOfContacts;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_of_contacts, container, false);
        mRecyclerview = view.findViewById(R.id.loc_r_view);
        listOfContactsRAdapter = new ListOfContactsRAdapter(getActivity(), this, arrayList);
        mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mRecyclerview.setAdapter(listOfContactsRAdapter);
        mRecyclerview.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerview.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        mRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                arrayList.addAll(Objects.requireNonNull(getArguments().<ContactModel>getParcelableArrayList("listofcontacts")));
                Log.d(TAG, "contact recived " + arrayList.get(0).getContactName());

            } else {
                if (getArguments().getStringArrayList("listofcontacts") != null)
                    arrayList.addAll(getArguments().<ContactModel>getParcelableArrayList("listofcontacts"));

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDueListener(int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDueListener: ");
        ContactModel contactModel = new ContactModel();
        contactModel.setContactName(arrayList.get(position).getContactName());
        contactModel.setContactNumberp(arrayList.get(position).getContactNumberp());
        contactModel.setState(true);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddDue.class);
        intent.putExtra("userDetails", contactModel);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

```
public ListOfContactsRAdapter(Context context, OnContactListener a, ArrayList<ContactModel> arrayList) {
    Log.d(TAG, "ListOfContactsRAdapter: +" + arrayList.size());
    ContactListener = a;
    this.arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (arrayList != null)
        this.arrayList.addAll(arrayList);
    mContext = context;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.loc_r_container, viewGroup, false);

    customViewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view, ContactListener);
    return customViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int i) {
    customViewHolder.contactName.setText(arrayList.get(i).getContactName());
    customViewHolder.contactNumber.setText(arrayList.get(i).getContactNumberp());
    customViewHolder.contactDp.setText(String.valueOf(arrayList.get(i).getContactName().charAt(0)));

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getItemCount: ");
    return arrayList.size();
}


static class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    OnContactListener Listener;
    TextView contactName;
    TextView contactNumber;
    TextView contactDp;
    Button button;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    CustomViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnContactListener mOnContactListener) {
        super(itemView);
        contactName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
        contactNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_number);
        button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.action);
        contactDp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contactDp);
        linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
        Listener = mOnContactListener;
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: ");
        Listener.onDueListener(getAdapterPosition());


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What i did is create an **Interface** in your RecyclerView Adapter:

```
public interface OnClickItem { // create an interface
    void onClickItem(int position); // create callback function
}
```

Then in **OnBindViewHolder**:

```
customViewHolder.(yourView).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               ContactListener.onClickItem(customViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
});
```

In your **Fragment**:

```
public class ListOfContacts extends Fragment implements ListOfContactsRAdapter.OnClickItem { ...
```

Implement the **method**:

```
@Override
  public void onClickItem(int position) {
  ... 
  }
```

Comment: i have used this code nothimg works...my full project source code https://github.com/arunabimanyu7/EUdhar

Comment: Okay i'll let you know if i can fix this.